# Weird sets behavior in python REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

I am new to python and constantly use REPL to check some code snippets.

I was trying to check if a set contains a tuple, based only on the first value in the tuple. Knowing that `_` in python means `pass`, I wrote something like this:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = {('a',1),('b',2)}
>>> x
{('b', 2), ('a', 1)}
>>> ('a',_) in x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> ('a',1) in x
True
>>> ('a',_) in x
True
```

So as you can see the first `('a',_) in x` statement resulted in a `TypeError`, but the next one gave an output without an error.

Can someone please explain what happened here?

Comment: "Knowing that `_` in python means `pass`,' *it does not mean `pass`*. `_` is just a normal variable name, like `foo` or `x`. In the REPL, it is assigned the *last* output. In Python code, it is *conventionally* used as a name for a throw-away variable, like to make a list of ten 1s,  `[1 for _ in range(10)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_` is set to the last non-`None` result returned by the repl. Thus `>>> ('a',_) in x` is the same as `>>> ('a', True) in x`. Note also that `True` is a special case of `1` in Python.